# Selecting an item in the DataGrid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm having an issue identifying a row and selecting the item in selenium.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Background:
This table is a user registration table where a system admin can select a registered user and assign permissions to the user.

HTML Code:

```
<table role="grid">
  <thead id="usersForm:usersTable_head">
  <tfoot/>
  <tbody id="usersForm:usersTable_data" class="ui-datatable-data ui-widget-content">
    <tr class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even ui-state-hover" aria-selected="false" role="row" data-rk="user1" data-ri="0">
      <td role="gridcell">1, User (user1)</td>
      <td role="gridcell">
        <span id="usersForm:usersTable:0:roles">6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd" aria-selected="false" role="row" data-rk="user2" data-ri="1">
      <td role="gridcell">2, User (user2)</td>
      <td role="gridcell">
        <span id="usersForm:usersTable:1:roles">22</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Ideally, I would be able to identify the object by the `<tr>` attribute "data-rk" as it has the username without the need to parse any information or do a partial text search.  I appreciate anyone's help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath:

```
string username = "user2";
By.XPath(".//tbody[@id='usersForm:usersTable_data']/tr[@data-rk='" + username + "']");
```

Css Selector (note the colon in your `tbody` id)

```
string username = "user2";
By.CssSelector("#usersForm\\\:usersTable_data > tr[data-rk='" + username + "']");
```

Comment: Used the Xpath version...Works like a Champ!  Thanks a million!